# How do I install boost log on c++ xe2

Tags: logging, boost, c++builder, c++builder-xe2

I know there is Boost library in XE2. And currently I want to add [Boost Log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial.html). As there is no document about installation with C++ builder. I just copy the relative files into "boost" and "libs" folders (C:\Program Files\Embarcadero\RAD Studio\9.0\include\boost_1_39). And after I added the `#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>`. I saw tons of errors...

Is there any tutorial or sample to show how to install Boost Log that I can follow?

Comment: There is no mention of C++ Builder in the list of supported compilers, except that versions later than 5.5.1 "might or might not work." The Boost version you have is 12 releases behind the current Boost release. Nonetheless, please restrict this question to asking how to install Boost.Log in C++ Builder. Don't ask for alternative log libraries because it will detract from the main question of how to install. Ask about other libraries in a separate question.

Comment: Removed the `delphi` tag. Even though Delphi is part of RAD Studio, it can't possibly use Boost Log (which is C++ only), and so there's no way this question concerns Delphi. Anyone who uses C++Builder will be able to recognize it, but if people using Delphi only see the tag it's meaningless.

Comment: Thanks for replies. I have edited my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++Builder only shipped with a limited subset of boost because those that didn't ship we're too problematic for people to use. Many of them won't compile or fail at runtime. I have high hopes for the upcoming clang-based compiler, which has must better language compliance.